# Scoliossis exercises at Gym

Tags: side-effects, exercise, scoliosis

I have scoliossis.I went to 2 doctors and they send me to get some kinetotherapy .

I asked them what can I do with my problem.I asked them if I can go to the gym and they said that I can **only** go to the swimming pool.
Both doctors are women if that matters.

Are they right? Aren't any exercises that I can do at the gym?Since I didn't went to the gym my muscles became smaller and I feel like my learning speed had decreased because I don't move and I don't get enough oxigen.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the doctors said you shouldn't exercise in gym at all? Or that only swimming would help with the problem not gym?

Comment: You need to ask them why, since they're the ones who said it.  We can't diagnose you. Also, in what way could it matter if the doctors were women?

Comment: @Džuris yes they said that I can't at all

Comment: @DoctorWhom as arguments the women said that gym is a sweaty place and swimming is not..

Comment: @DoctorWhom unfourtunately, it's quite possible that the doctors are not that much into gym. Some 12 years ago my scoliosis was discovered and I asked the doctor if I can go to gym. He said "no, you may not lift weights". I assumed that he imagines "gym" to mean "olympic weightlifting" or similar and visited a sports doctor who told me basically the same as in the answer by D Bagnall.

Comment: I was just pointing out that commenting about the doctors being female was rather odd.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are exercises that place no stress on the spine and couldn't worsen your scoliosis. Leg extensions using machine, preacher curls, pec flys are some examples of exercises that doesn't involve the spine at all.

Other exercises like shoulder press, deadlifts, squats put pressure and stresses on the spine and might be more risky with certain back conditions. If doctors advise against gym, these might be the exercises that you are supposed to avoid.

I am not sure about the scientific consensus but it is believed (by both doctors and laymen) that scoliosis may lead to uneven pressures that can lead to disc protrusions and some other trauma easier than normally. So you should (as any person) take extreme care and control your back (and whole body) not only during exercise, but also when carrying weights, preparing for exercise and putting weights down after the exercise. This might be the other reason why doctors advise you against visiting the gym.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, but please avoid giving medical advice.  If both doctors really told the OP not to do anything but swim, there might be something other than just the scoliosis behind that recommendation.  Almost anything physical you do involves the spine to one degree or another, as it is the axial skeleton.  I think the OP is incorrect in how he understood the advice.  Or else there's something more serious going on.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Now I''m scared

Comment: Can you name another exercises for chest and triceps please? So I can't do exercises in which I stand up and the weights are moving up and down

Comment: Maybe try consulting a physiotherapist or a doctor specialised in sports. Bring your X-rays (if possible) and tell them your condition and your goals (that you want to visit gym etc).

Comment: @Džuris I went to kinetotherapy to 2 different doctors(different from the doctors from the post).First said that I could do almost anything I want,even back exercises and the other one said that I can't do anything just swimming because the doctor said that.This made me confused.Also both doctors from the post wrote the scoliossis problem in different way on papers and both said that the other doctor is wrong so this got me confused .

Answer (score 0):

Scoliosis is a natural and very common phenomenon.  Generally we don't see or feel scoliosis, rather, it is something that shows up by chance on an x-ray.

People with mild scoliosis are not limited by it, and exercise, all kinds of exercise, is not harmful.  I encourage my patients to exercise as much as they want, regardless of the type of exercise they choose.

Exercise will not correct scoliosis, but it's not important that mild scoliosis be corrected as it is neither painful or harmful.